# How to attach VS2005 to process running on WinCe 5.0

Tags: debugging, windows-mobile, visual-studio-2005, windows-ce

What applications/modules/dlls do I need on the Window CE 5.0 device in order to be able to attach Visual Studio 2005 to process running on the device ?

Answer (score 4):

In the Debug menu, select Attach to process...
In the dialog that pops up change Transport to Smart Device.
Hit the Browse button and pick the type of device.
It'll pop up a connecting dialog, when it disappears, you get a list of processes on the device.

Pick the one you want to debug and the debugger will start up.

This should work on at least Standard VS2005, as long as you selected Smart device development during install (Express doesn't support smart devices).

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure you have a CoreCon connection.  This can be done via ActiveSync (which I don't recommend) or directly via Ethernet.  It's a fiarly straightforward process, though a little to lengthy to post here clearly, but it entails running the CoreCon client on the device and setting Studio's Device Connectivity options to the device IP.  There's an [article over at OpenNETCF](http://community.opennetcf.com/articles/cf/archive/2007/08/31/debugging-without-activesync.aspx) that covers how to make the connection that works from Studio '05 or '08.